# Magento 2.3: How can I add PayPal Express Checkout integration on custom page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, payment-gateway, paypal-express

I'm new to magento.I'm working on magento 2 custom checkout module due to integration with client ERP system.

All of my checkout process are using custom table like `custom_order_table` and `custom_order_items_table`.

My question is how can I add PayPal Checkout button on my custom page and when click the button retrieve data from my custom table etc .. `grand_total,currency,item_detils` and submit to PayPal to complete payment process.

Please help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Please follow the checkout_cart_index.xml layout in the PayPal module. You will get an idea to add that button on the custom page.

Comment: Thank You for your advice @Nits .I already tried may different way still cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to add a button on your custom page.

1) Review this block and do the required changes in your custom module file.

> /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/QuoteShortcutButtons.php

2) Add this code in your custom page block file (php)

```
    /**
     * Dispatch shortcuts container event
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'shortcut_buttons_container',
            [
                'container' => $this,
                'is_catalog_product' => $this->_isCatalogProduct,
                'or_position' => $this->_orPosition
            ]
        );
        return $this;
    }
```

I have not checked in detail but logic is the "shortcut_buttons_container" event configured this button and it will render on particular page section.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Nits but not working.